# Scaling the animated image size on Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

```
<div id="dragon" style="position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 400px;  width:90px; height:90px;">

   <script language="JavaScript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load",animateImagesStart,false);
else if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload",animateImagesStart);
 });


function animateImagesStart() {

var imgs=[
        "image/dragon/drag0.png", "image/dragon/drag1.png", "image/dragon/drag2.png",    "image/dragon/drag3.png",  "image/dragon/drag4.png", "image/dragon/drag5.png", "image/dragon/drag6.png", "image/dragon/drag7.png", "image/dragon/drag8.png","image/dragon/drag9.png"
    ];

// preloading images
var img,count=imgs.length,

    imageLoadComplete=function(ev) {
        if(ev.type=="error")imgs.splice(imgs.indexOf(this),1);
    };

for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    img=new Image();
    img.onerror=imageLoadComplete;
    img.src=imgs[i];
    imgs[i]=img;
}

var domImg=document.getElementById("dragon"),
    currentImageIndex=0,
    animateImages=function(){
        if(currentImageIndex>=imgs.length)currentImageIndex=0;
        if(imgs[currentImageIndex].complete)domImg.style.backgroundImage="URL("+imgs[currentImageIndex].src+")";

        currentImageIndex++;
        setTimeout(animateImages,1000);
    };
setTimeout(animateImages,0);
```

}

Right now, the animated image is small, just default image size, how can I scale it to bigge r size?  I try if(imgs[currentImageIndex].complete)domImg.style.backgroundImage.height='200px';
              if(imgs[currentImageIndex].complete)domImg.style.backgroundImage.width='200px';
This didn't do anything.

And I also try
  now instead of bigger animated size, there are 4 instances of animated images , all of them same size and the original size.

What I want is one instance of animated image and scale it bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [background-size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) CSS declaration to scale the background image.  Background image scaling isn't directly associated with the dimensions of the node to which the background is applied.  By default, backgrounds will render at whatever resolution the original image is and tile to fit whatever node they are assigned to (which is why you were seeing multiple background images when you increased the size of the div).

Just be mindful that background-size is supported in IE9 and up but not below.  (All of the other major browsers have supported it for a while now.)  If you need to support IE8 and lower, you'll probably need to inject an actual img tag that's scaled to what you want and use z-index to ensure it renders behind other nodes.